# Glyph alternation issues with Junicode

Tags: xetex, fontspec, junicode

I've got an issue with a specific glyph alternation in Junicode---namely, the italic `k` has a particular variant before `i` that I find not particularly attractive. You can see in the image here how it's occurs only before `i`.

[image: note that the k has a long foot before i]

It's a neat idea, but the spacing makes it look rather odd, and I'd like to avoid using it. The Junicode documentation says nothing about this particular alternation, though, and I've tried turning off and on a variety of font features, to no avail (it's not a part of any stylistic set, and it's unaffected by ligatures settings).

Is there a way I can globally bypass this particular alternation in exactly this context without a built-in font option to do so?

MWE, which produces the above:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Junicode}

\begin{document}
    \textit{
    ka kb kc kd ke kf kg kh ki kj kl km kn ko kp kq kr ks kt ku kv kw kx ky kz  
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any chance you can switch from XeLaTeX to LuaLaTeX? With LuaLaTeX, the shape of  italic-`k` if it occurs right before `i` is not unusual.

Comment: Does a manual intervention of `k{}i` fix it? (I don't have the font)

Comment: If no other solution lends itself, you could employ the "brute-force" approach of replacing all instances of `ki` with `k\kern0pti`. (This works with both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.)

Comment: As far as I can see, this is a ligature included in the standard `liga` feature. If you disable it, you disable also all the other standard ligatures.

Comment: I edited the font and removed `k_i` from the `liga` table and the ligature vanishes. You could try the “interchartoks” feature of XeTeX, but this will have adverse effects on hyphenation.

Comment: Running LuaLaTeX doesn't actually seem to have any effect for me. I'd prefer to not have to do brute-force solutions (as this may happen hundreds of times in this document), so editing the font seems like the way to  go. @egreg How exactly would I go about doing this? (Also, can anyone speak to the rationale behind this variation?)

Answer (score 3):

This isn’t a solution for xetex, but if you can compile your document with luatex, there’s no need to edit the font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "noki",
    type = "multiple",
    data = {
      ["k_i"] = { "k", "i" },
    },
  }
}
\setmainfont{Junicode}[
RawFeature=+noki]
\begin{document}
ki

\textit{ka kb kc kd ke kf kg kh ki kj kl km kn ko kp kq kr ks kt ku kv
  kw kx ky kz}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you! Running LuaLaTeX seems to be vastly slower for me, but I'll use this when I'm compiling the final product.